# XGBoost feature importance giving the results for 10 features

Tags: python, xgboost, feature-selection, data-preprocessing

I am trying to use XGBoost as a feature importance tool. However, out of 84 features, I got only results for only 10 of them and the for the rest of them prints zeros. Do you know how to fix it?

This is my code and the results:

```
import numpy as np
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from xgboost import plot_importance
from matplotlib import pyplot

X = data.iloc[:,:-1]
y = data['clusters_pred']

model = XGBClassifier()
model.fit(X, y)

sorted_idx = np.argsort(model.feature_importances_)[::-1]
for index in sorted_idx:
    print([X.columns[index], model.feature_importances_[index]])
```

```
['XYZ', 0.97976303]
['ABC', 0.008309732]
['ZZZ', 0.007930854]
['CGNK', 0.0011405549]
['TTT', 0.0011277349]
['PLT', 0.0007475067]
['HB', 0.00056899816]
['PBB', 0.00020151233]
['AGE', 0.000108826855]
['SEX', 0.0001012349]
['BLA', 0.0]
['STAT', 0.0]
['tRU', 0.0]
...
```

Comment: What should be fixed here? Apparently, some features have zero importance. You should probably delete them and keep only the ones with high enough importance.

Comment: But there is no way that 10 of 84 have only values. I used other methods and each feature got some value.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your 'XYZ' feature is turning out to be the most important compared to others and as per the important values - it is suggested to drop the lower important features.
You can try with different feature combination, try some normalization on the existing feature or try with different feature important type used in XGBClassifier e.g.  “gain”, “weight”, “cover”, “total_gain” or “total_cover”. The default is 'weight'.